# Applicative instances for Reader, Writer and State

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I understand applicative vs monad style of programming, but most articles discuss this distinction with "simple" monads like `Maybe`.

But what about monads like `Reader`, `Writer` and `State`. Are there pracrical examples of using them in applicative way?

Comment: Arbitrary example: the applicative instance of `State` can be used to [implement `mapAccumL`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41523456/2751851).

Answer (score 3):

Every time you use the `foo <$> bar <*> baz` idom with monadic functions `bar` and `baz`, you are using a Monad in an applicative way. This is not a very deep use of `Applicative`, but rather a convenient way of writing a bit of code, and independent of the `Monad` – and hence you will find this style also for `Reader`, `Writer` and `State`.